# passing a url as a param in a Laravel 4 Route

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to pass a url as part of my Route:
i.e

> http://example.com/param1/url_param

or

> http://example.com/param1/?url_param=http://example1.com/56474

```
Route::get('/{param1}/{url_param?}', function($param1, $url_param){});
```

I'm on Ubuntu, nginx, Laravel 4.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem? Both of your approaches look fine. The route you posted will work if the first URL looks like this `http://example.com/param1/http://example1.com/56474`. The second one will work if you access the `url_param` with `Request::input('url_param')` (of course you'll need to remove the `{url_param?}` from the route definition.

Comment: in the first example if the link is >http://example.com/param1/http://example1.com it gets broken and redirected to the home route.

Comment: You may want to encode the url param as well

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass that URL without encoding it via parameter. Furthermore, you cannot pass it like in the first example (appending it as a segment of the URL) as you have the segment delimiter char inside the URL ('/') to define the protocol.

The second example would be right though, although I'd recommend you to encode the URL using url_encode().

Another approach to this would be to encode the URL using B64, producing a string that can be appended as a URL segment. Something like:

```
$URLToBeAppended = base64_encode( 'http://example1.com/564740' );
```

And now the final route would look something like:

> http://example.com/param1/aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUxLmNvbS81NjQ3NDA=

In the controller responsible for handling that route you can just decode that B64 string.